# Using Sass to create a dynamic animation list

Tags: css, animation, sass, mixins, extends

So, I've been messing around with creating a bit of code in CSS that is a list of animations set for one element. It's basically just a loop, but I need to be able to change the timing of each time it goes off. Basically, I'd like something as simple as this:

```
$intro-duration:1s;
$intro-delay:6.5s;
$intro-separation:0.7s;
$intro-style:ease;

@mixin intro($multiplier) {
-webkit-animation:intro $intro-duration $intro-separation*$multiplier+$intro-delay $intro-style;
}

.intro {
   @include intro(-1);
   @include intro(0);
   @include intro(1);
   @include intro(2);
   @include intro(3);
}
```

But having that, it comes out like:

```
.intro {
  -webkit-animation: intro 1s 5.8s ease;
  -webkit-animation: intro 1s 6.5s ease;
  -webkit-animation: intro 1s 7.2s ease;
  -webkit-animation: intro 1s 7.9s ease;
  -webkit-animation: intro 1s 8.6s ease;
}
```

Which would be all fine and dandy, but I obviously need to be able to leave off the "-webkit-animation" as well as the semi-colon in place of a commas, in order to properly combine the string of animation. So it needs to be this:

```
.intro {
  -webkit-animation: 
  intro 1s 5.8s ease,
  intro 1s 6.5s ease,
  intro 1s 7.2s ease,
  intro 1s 7.9s ease,
  intro 1s 8.6s ease; }
```

I totally feel like I'm really just over complicating it and feel that if I were to simply step away from it for a few hours, I'd come up with the solution, but I've tried a few different things and am coming up short. Any help to simplify this code would be much appreciated!

EDIT: Removed a few lines of the repeating code to try and keep it simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a list:

```
@mixin intro($multiplier...) {
  $collector: ();
  @each $i in $multiplier {
    $collector: append($collector, intro $intro-duration $intro-separation* $i+ $intro-delay $intro-style, comma);
  }
  animation: $collector;
}

.intro {
  @include intro(-1, 0, 1, 2, 3);
}
```

Alternately:

```
@mixin intro($start, $end) {
  $collector: ();
  @for $i from $start through $end {
    $collector: append($collector, intro $intro-duration $intro-separation* $i+ $intro-delay $intro-style, comma);
  }
  animation: $collector;
}

.intro {
  @include intro(-1, 3);
}
```

And make sure you're providing all prefixes (as appropriate) + non-prefixed properties, not just webkit prefixes.

Comment: Ah man. You're awesome. I really appreciate it! I don't think I'd have come to this conclusion even if I had stepped away for a few hours.